# Display logic error with settimeout

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to ajax and php ..I have a php script which displays a two digit number 1 and 2..What i need is i just want to display the number 1 after 3 seconds and display the other number 2 after 3 seconds and i want to clear that intervel..This is what i have tried..

## Ajax.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var d = setInterval(function babe () {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var str = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var res = str.split("");
console.log(res[0]);
   
      
       setInterval(function() { console.log(res[2]); }, 5555);
    }
}




xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();


setInterval(function() { clearInterval(d);}, 3000);
}, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code outputs 1 two times and it continously executes 2 without ending.

what i need is to execute `1` after 3 seconds and `2` after 3 seconds and clear the interval..

Thanx for the help folks..:)

Comment: can't understand your code... too many functions in functions... can you at least indent it please ? Here I see a call to `setInterval(...)` inside the `setInterval(...)` function... looks like there is a problem....

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is continuously performc

```
setInterval(function() { console.log(res[2]); }, 5555);
```

is continously executes 2

you can try

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(res[2]); }, 3000);
```

close d after 3 second

```
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(d);}, 3000);
```